# Overcoming vnode_proxy_timeout in a big riak mapreduce

Tags: riak

I have a riak bucket which contains roughly 16million records.  I'm trying to get my feet wet with mapreduce by running a simple count over all the keys in the bucket:

```
curl -v -d '{"inputs":"mybucket", 
             "timeout": 86400000, 
             "query":[
               {"map":{
                 "language":"erlang",
                 "module":"riak_kv_mapreduce",
                 "function":"map_identity"}
               },
               {"reduce":{
                  "language":"erlang",
                   "module":"riak_kv_mapreduce",
                   "function":"reduce_count_inputs"}
               }
             ]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://riak01:8098/mapred
```

However, I receive the following error, after a few minutes of spinning:

```
{"phase":0,"error":"[{vnode_proxy_timeout,{251195593916248939066258330623111144003363405824,'riak@10.40.239.99'}}]","input":"{ok,{r_object,<<\"mybucket\">>,<<\"oneofmykeys\">>,[{r_content,{dict,6,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[[<<\"content-type\">>,(mycontenttype)],[<<\"X-Riak-VTag\">>,53,116,122,97,99,76,103,112,51,115,50,79,90,71,53,80,89,81,116,119,105,54]],[[<<\"index\">>]],[],[[<<\"X-Riak-Last-Modified\">>|{1383,386589,424337}]],[],[[<<\"X-Riak-Meta\">>,{<<\"...\">>,<<\"...\">>}],...]}}},...}],...},...}","type":"result","stack":"[{gen,do_call,4,[{file,\"gen.erl\"},{line,234}]},{riak_core_vnode_proxy,call,2,[{file,\"src/riak_core_vnode_proxy.erl\"},{line,109}]},{riak_pipe_vnode,queue_work_send,4,[{file,\"src/riak_pipe_vnode.erl\"},{line,333}]},{riak_pipe_vnode,queue_work_erracc,6,[{file,\"src/riak_pipe_vnode.erl\"},{line,281}]},{riak_kv_mrc_map,send_results,2,[{file,\"src/riak_kv_mrc_map.erl\"},{line,232}]},{riak_pipe_vnode_worker,process_input,3,[{file,\"src/riak_pipe_vnode_worker.erl\"},{line,445}]},{riak_pipe_vnode_worker,wait_for_input,...},...]"}
```

I realize that spinning through the whole bucket's keys can be slow, but I'd like some reassurance that in a pinch, I can map through my entire bucket in some way.  **How do I address vnode_proxy_timeout errors?**

Answer (score 2):

"vnode_proxy_timeout" CANNOT be specified as suggested by "thesam". It's just WRONG - nothing will read this from the HTTP request.

**vnode_proxy_timeout** is only thrown from one place inside Riak:

https://github.com/basho/riak_pipe/blob/develop/src/riak_pipe_vnode.erl#L342

It's a rethrow of the gen_server timeout happening here:

https://github.com/basho/riak_core/blob/develop/src/riak_core_vnode_proxy.erl#L109

Since the gen:call from Riak doesn't specify a Timeout, gen defaults to 5s. 
https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/gen.erl#L146

Unfortunately, there's no way to change this without changing and compiling Riak source code.

If you use a range search as input to the Map-Reduce job, consider splitting the range up in a number of non-overlapping sub-ranges. Say, if you want to map reduce over data with keys in the range [a-z], then do it sequentially as multiple map reduce-calls. One for each of [a-e], [e-h], [i-s], [t-z] for instance.

With this approach, if one of the subrange MR jobs fails, say [i-s] times out, you only need to rerun the mapreduce of [i-s] and not all your input data [a-z]. Divide and conquer.

Answer (score -1):

In the same way you have set the timeout, you can set the vnode_proxy_timeout. For example:

```
{
    "inputs": "mybucket",
    "vnode_proxy_timeout": 99999999,
...
```